# Overloading .Where extension with IQueryable<T> implementation

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, orm, linq-to-entities

My question is how / when it makes sense to overload (if thats possible?) the Where() **extension** method of IQueryable when you are making your own IQueryable implementation?

For example in Entity Framework its my understanding that a Where() call made against an ObjectSet will change the actual SQL thats being passed to the database. Alternatively if you cast to IEnumerable() first the filtering is done with LINQ-To-Objects rather than LINQ-To-Entities.

For instance:

```
new MyDBEntities().MyDbTable.Where(x => x.SomeProperty == "SomeValue"); 
  // this is linq-to-entities and changes the database-level SQL
```

Versus:

```
new MyDBEntities().MyDbTable.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.SomeProperty == "SomeValue"); 
  // this is linq-to-objects and filters the IEnumerable
```

How do you deal with this when implementing your own IQueryable and IQueryable already has pre-defined extension methods such as Where()? Specifically I want make my own very simple ORM that uses native SQL and SqlDataReader under the hood, and want to have a .Where() method that changes the native SQL before passing it to the database.

Should I even use IQueryable or just create my own class entirely? I want to be able to use lambda syntax and have my SQL command altered based on the lambda function(s) used for filtration.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is helpful, but you may want to at least read up on relinq: http://relinq.codeplex.com/  They may have done some of what you are looking for already (it's open source).  Or maybe there is no overlap at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* create your own type analogous to `IQueryable<T>`, but that's probably not a good idea. You should probably write your own implementation of the interface. [There is a nice series of articles on how to do it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2008/11/18/linq-links.aspx), but be prepared, doing so is not one of the easier tasks.

Comment: If you roll your own implementation of IQueryable<T> and do all that expression visitor work, do you automatically get a custom .Where() extension method, or do you have to write your own .Where() extension method against your new type that derives from IQueryable ie public static MyQueryableImpl<T> Where(this MyQueryableImpl<T>, Func<T, bool> filter)..

Comment: If you do that, the `Queryable.Where()` method will do what you need. That's what it's for. So, no, you don't need to implement your own `Where()`, but you need to write code that translated expression containing call to `Where()` to correct SQL.